# Calculating the given integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Define $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by 
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1& \text{ $x$ is algebraic}\\0 
> &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> The question is to find $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$.

My Try:

Take a partition $P=\Bigl\{0=\frac{0}{n},\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\frac{3}{n},...,\frac{n}{n}=1\Bigr\}$ of $[0,1]$.

Since every transcentendal number is irrational and irrational are dense, so the minimum over each subinterval is $0$. Hence $L(P,f)=0$.

On the other hand, to calculating $U(P,f)$, we see that $\Delta x_i=\frac{1}{n}, \forall i.$. Also the maximum over each subinterval is $1$, so $U(P,f)=\Sigma_1^n M_i \Delta x_i \neq 0$. So lower integral and upper integral are different.

But the answer was  $\int_0^1 f(x) dx=0$.

Where I'm doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: the set of all algebraic number is countable.so...?

Comment: You start from the fact that the algebraic numbers, numerous as they may be, are _countable_...

Comment: There is likely an issue with how integration is defined.  For the Riemann integral your approach is valid.  The upper and lower sums do not converge as the partitions of $[0,1]$ are refined, so the Riemann integral does not exist for this (very discontinuous) function.  On the other hand the Lebesgue integral definition does give the zero "answer" that you ask about finally.

Comment: Riemann integral doesn't exist. Lebesgue integral does.

Comment: May I ask where this question is from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Riemann integral doesn't exist, well spotted. The Lebesgue integral is 0, because the integrand is 0 almost everywhere (except for algebraic arguments, but that's a countable set having Lebesgue measure 0).
**EDIT:** Let's make that a bit more detailed. The Riemann integral $\int^1_0f(x)\,dx$ can't exist, and we wouldn't even need upper and lower sums: both algebraic and transcendental numbers are dense, so for any partition $(x_i)$ of $[0,1]$, we can find $\xi_i\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ both with $f(\xi_i)=0$ or with $f(\xi_i)=1$, so the Riemann sums $\sum_i f(\xi_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)$ can't converge.
So the integral in your given answer can't be a Riemann integral. You don't say which one, but the most common generalization is the Lebesgue integral. That's uniquely defined by some properties: the integral of an indicator function $\chi_A(x)$ of a Borel set $A$ is the Lebesgue measure $\mu(A)$ of that set, the integral is linear in the integrand, and positive for positive integrands.
In your case,  it's simpler, because your integrand is the indicator function  of a set, the set $A$ of algebraic numbers in $[0,1]$. That's a countable set, so $\int^1_0f(x)\,dx=\mu(A)=0$.
All countable sets have Lebesgue measure zero, and it's easy to see why: the measure is uniquely defined by the requirement $\mu([a,b])=b-a$, so $\mu(\{a\})=\mu([a,a])=a-a=0$, and since it is $\sigma$-additive (additive for countable unions of disjoint sets), we see $\mu(A)=\sum_{a\in A}\mu(\{a\})=0$.

Comment: Thank you, Professor Vector!

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is Riemann-integrate this function. However, this function cannot be Riemann-integrated, for the following reason:

What is a Riemann integral? It's just the limit of a Riemann sum. However, this Riemann sum will only accurately reflect the actual integral if the function is *piecewise continuous* - otherwise, there are many points $x$ where the value being taken for $f(x)$ in the Riemann sum doesn't actually approach $f(x)$. This is one such case.

To integrate it, we must use the Lebesgue integral. As Professor Vector said, the Lebesgue integral of a function that is $0$ almost everywhere is $0$. And, this function is $0$ almost everywhere because the set of places where it isn't (algebraic numbers) has countable cardinality, while we are integrating over an uncountable set.